# How to pass a user_id to a custom plugin

Tags: plugin-development

This may not be the best way to do this.
The client needs to be able to enroll users **into custom courses** that's defined in another post_type.  I can't find any documentation that allows me to add a custom link or tabs to the profile.php using a custom plugin.
So I've tried adding an extra column to the users.php page. I want to use the built-in users.php or profile.php and just hook into it so the admins don't have to search a separate interface for users to register them into this custom course work.

I've got the link shows up with the correct user id using the code below.

```
add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', function( $columns )
{
    return array_slice( $columns, 0, 2, true ) 
        + [ 'mycol' => __( 'Register' ) ] 
        + array_slice( $columns, 3, null, true );
} );

add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', function( $output, $column_name, $user_id )
{
    if( 'mycol' === $column_name )
    {
        $u = new WP_User( $user_id ); 
        if( $u instanceof \WP_User )
        {
            // Default output
            $output .= "$u->first_name $u->last_name $u->ID ";

            // Extra output
           $output .= "<p><a href='admin.php?page=home-study?user_id=".$u->ID."'>Register HS</a></p>";

            // Housecleaning
            unset( $u ); 
        }
    }       
    return $output;
}, 10, 3 );
```

This works great and gives me something like:
[image]

I've started on a custom plugin and have a basic page created that will just echo "I'm Here" when rendered.  I simply want to pass the user_id to the page.  But when I do, I get the "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page."
page=home-study?user_id=1

But, when I remove the parameters and just direct the link to go to the home-study page, it works fine.
page=home-study

I'm an admin of the site.  Seems like a permission issue, but I can't figure out what's wrong.

Thanks
Max

Comment: Use gist or simliar to share your plugin code. Otherwise people here can only guess re a solution.  https://gist.github.com/